# How do I define a new numeric constant in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

What is the best way to define a numerical constant in Mathematica?

For example, say I want `g` to be the approximate acceleration due to gravity on the surface of the Earth. I give it a numerical value (in `m/s^2`), tell Mathematica it's numeric, positive and a constant using

```
Unprotect[g];
ClearAll[g]
N[g] = 9.81;
NumericQ[g] ^= True;
Positive[g] ^= True;
SetAttributes[g, Constant];
Protect[g];
```

Then I can use it as a symbol in symbolic calculations that will automatically evaluate to 9.81 when numerical results are called for. For example `1.0 g` evaluates to `9.81`.

This does not seem as well tied into Mathematica as built in numerical constants. For example `Pi > 0` will evaluate to `True`, but `g > 0` will not. (I could add `g > 0` to the global `$Assumptions` but even then I need a call to `Simplify` for it to take effect.) 
Also, `Positive[g]` returns `True`, but `Positive[g^2]` does not evaluate - compare this with the equivalent statements using `Pi`.

So my question is, what else should I do to define a numerical constant? What other attributes/properties can be set? Is there an easier way to go about this? Etc...

Comment: [Here's an answer/discussion](http://designerunits.com/stackoverflow8275850) given by the author of the [Designer Units package](http://designerunits.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend using a zero-argument "function". That way it can be given both the NumericFunction attribute and a numeric evaluation rule. that latter is important for predicates such as Positive.

```
SetAttributes[gravUnit, NumericFunction]
N[gravUnit[], prec_: $MachinePrecision] := N[981/100, prec]

In[121]:= NumericQ[gravitUnit[]]
Out[121]= True

In[122]:= Positive[gravUnit[]^2 - 30]
Out[122]= True
```

Daniel Lichtblau

Comment: Apart from having to carry around the `[]`, this seems to have all the properties that I was looking for. The former can be fixed with some custom notation, so *tick*!

Comment: OK, I just found this.  Is this formulation as a function with `NumericFunction` attribtue better than `NumericQ[g] = True`?  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128444/12

Comment: Also, based on `Default[N, 2]`, shouldn't `prec_ : ` be followed by `{MachinePrecision, MachinePrecision}` (no `$`) for consistency with other things?

Comment: @Szabolcs Probably it should be as you suggest, and the person who proposed this is guilty of some sort of software infraction. But the five year statue of limitations on this will soon expire so I am disinclined to prosecute absent a stronger case.

Answer (score 3):

May be I am naive, but to my mind your definitions are a good start. Things like `g > 0->True` can be added via `UpValues`. For `Positive[g^2]` to return `True`, you probably have to overload `Positive`, because of the depth-1 limitation for `UpValues`. Generally, I think the exact set of auto-evaluated expressions involving a constant is a moving target, even for built-in constants. In other words, those extra built-in rules seem to be determined from convenience and frequent uses, on a case-by-case basis, rather than from the first principles. I would just add new rules as you go, whenever you feel that you need them. You probably can not expect your constants to be as well integrated in the system as built-ins, but I think you can get pretty close. You will probably have to overload a number of built-in functions on these symbols, but again, which ones those will be,  will depend on what you need from your symbol.

**EDIT**

I was hesitating to include this, since the code below is a hack, but it *may* be useful in some circumstances. Here is the code:

```
Clear[evalFunction];
evalFunction[fun_Symbol, HoldComplete[sym_Symbol]] := False;

Clear[defineAutoNValue];
defineAutoNValue[s_Symbol] :=
  Module[{inSUpValue},
    s /: expr : f_[left___, s, right___] :=
      Block[{inSUpValue = True},
        With[{stack = Stack[_]},
          If[
            expr === Unevaluated[expr] &&
               (evalFunction[f, HoldComplete[s]] ||
                  MemberQ[
                    stack,
                    HoldForm[(op_Symbol /; evalFunction[op, HoldComplete[s]])
                       [___, x_ /; ! FreeQ[Unevaluated[x], HoldPattern@expr], ___]],
                    Infinity
                  ]
               ),
            f[left, N[s], right],
            (* else *)
            expr
      ]]] /; ! TrueQ[inSUpValue]];

ClearAll[substituteNumeric];
SetAttributes[substituteNumeric, HoldFirst];
substituteNumeric[code_, rules : {(_Symbol :> {__Symbol}) ..}] :=
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{evalFunction},
     MapThread[
       Map[Function[f, evalFunction[f, HoldComplete[#]] = True], #2] &,
       Transpose[List @@@ rules]
     ];
     code]
```

With this, you may enable a symbol to auto-substitute its numerical value in places where we indicate some some functions surrounding those function calls may benefit from it. Here is an example:

```
ClearAll[g, f];
SetAttributes[g, Constant];
N[g] = 9.81;
NumericQ[g] ^= True;
defineAutoNValue[g];
f[g] := "Do something with g";
```

Here we will try to compute some expressions involving `g`, first normally:

```
In[391]:= {f[g],g^2,g^2>0, 2 g, Positive[2 g+1],Positive[2g-a],g^2+a^2,g^2+a^2>0,g<0,g^2+a^2<0}
Out[391]= {Do something with g,g^2,g^2>0,2 g,Positive[1+2 g],
   Positive[-a+2 g],a^2+g^2,a^2+g^2>0,g<0,a^2+g^2<0}
```

And now inside our wrapper (the second argument gives a list of rules, to indicate for which symbols which functions, when wrapped around the code containing those symbols, should lead to those symbols being replaced with their numerical values):

```
In[392]:= 
substituteNumeric[{f[g],g^2,g^2>0, 2 g, Positive[2 g+1],Positive[2g-a],g^2+a^2,g^2+a^2>0,
      g<0,g^2+a^2<0},
     {g:>{Positive,Negative,Greater}}]

Out[392]= {Do something with g,g^2,True,2 g,True,Positive[19.62\[VeryThinSpace]-a],
a^2+g^2,96.2361\[VeryThinSpace]+a^2>0,g<0,a^2+g^2<0}
```

Since the above is a hack, I can not guarantee anything about it. It may be useful in some cases, but that must be decided on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: You're almost certainly not naive and probably correct about the rest of your answer. But I guess I was hoping for more...

Comment: @Simon You can try adding a rule like this: `g /: f_[left___, g, right___] /; ! MemberQ[{Clear, Remove, N}, f] :=  f[left, N[g], right]` at the very end. It will replace `g` with its numeric value for any function on `g` which does not evaluate. This however may not always be what is needed, since in will prevent both inert wrappers around `g` and functions with Hold-attributes to be applied to `g`, and also sometimes we don't want the result to be based on numeric value. Anyways, things like `Positive[g^3]` or `g>0` will work. This is certainly a hack rather than a recommended method though.

Comment: Leonid: I think that hack removes a bit too much flesh. It would make, e.g., `2 g` evaluate to its numerical value of `19.62`. But I understand what you were getting at.

Comment: @Simon I added a more "elaborate" version of my hack in the edit (not sure this was a right thing to do, but too large for a comment). It is still a hack (perhaps even worse), but it does address some of your critique on my previous one.

Comment: Cool hack, but Daniel's solution seems to behave almost exactly as I wanted, so I think I have to give him the tick.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider working with units rather than just constants.  There are a few options available in Mathematica

- [Units](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Units/tutorial/Units.html)
- [Automatic Units](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7655/)
- [Designer units](http://designerunits.com/overview)

There are quite a few technical issues and subtleties about working with units. I found the [backgrounder](http://designerunits.com/backgrounder) at Designer Units very useful. There are also some interesting discussions on MathGroup. (e.g. [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Jan/msg00427.html)).

Comment: Sure, the units packages can be handy. There was also a good [Wolfram blog post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/12/09/automatic-physical-units-in-mathematica/) related to the Automatic Units package.

Comment: However, there are physical constants - such as the [fine structure constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant) (and other fundamental dimensionless constants in QFT) that are dimensionless. Also mathematical constants that have no efficient calculational scheme, such as the [Feigenbaum constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FeigenbaumConstant.html). So the units packages aren't always what is needed. Also, you'd think that `1 Meter > 0` should return `True`...

Comment: I would expect "1 Meter > 0 Meter" to return true. But to me, it doesn't make sense to compare a measure to a number (e.g. "1 Meter > 0") any more than it does to compare measures of different dimensions (e.g "1 Meter > 1 Second").

Comment: For units with a definite zero (such as `Meter`, `Second` or `Kelvin`), then comparisons to zero make sense. For units that are [torsors](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/torsors.html) (like energy in classical physics or temperature in degrees Celsius), then comparison to zero is a bit meaningless.

Comment: Aside: 0 Meter will immediately evaluate to 0...  and 1 Meter ~= 3.34E-9 Second < 1 Second

Comment: My point was simply that zero is a number, not a measure. One cannot compare a measure to a number.  The story about defining a length by a time is whimsical.  In a poetic sense, I see your point.

Comment: I agree for an arbitrary number. But zero is rather special, so the comparison does make sense. For example, in vector/tensor calculations, if a tensor is zero in one basis/reference frame, then it is zero in all bases. (Of course, we're getting off topic here!)

Comment: @Simon, what other fundamental physical dimensionless constants are in QFT or in the whole physics ???  I thought the fine structure constant was the uniqe one!

Comment: @Harmonices: It's too complicated (and off topic) for a comment thread... so I think I'll just refer you to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_physical_constant) and [John Baez](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/constants.html). Email me if you have any more questions.

Comment: @Simon: Thanks, but I completely disagree. The both links contain abuses of the term fundamental. Well, any "constants" in the Standard Model are only pseudo fundamental ones as well as ratios of masses or strengths of so called "fundamental" forces. But  I'm not willing to be off topic.

Comment: @Harmonices: But if you consider the fine structure constant to be fundamental, you have to admit the other two gauge coupling constants. At almost the same level are the Yukawa Higgs-Fermion couplings. And these are proportional to the fermion masses. So in that sense, each fermion mass is associated with a dimensionless coupling constant.